# If a fairy enters an antimagic field, do they die?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, antimagic-field

According to the fairy description, fairies are infused with the magic of the feywild:

> Infused with the magic of the Feywild, most fairies look like Small elves with insectile wings…

Does this mean that if a fairy enters an antimagic field, it just dies?

Comment: Please do not post screen shots of text. Instead provide a link to the text and quote here as much as is necessary.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the heads up

Comment: In any event, is "die"- implying permanent cessation- appropriate in this context, or is there some alternative?

Comment: I was asking if the fairy would just stop existing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### No

As [minmass observes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/210776/75095), *antimagic field* does not kill creatures created by magic, but also, the game has two different categories of magical. ***Background*** magical, which is unaffected by *antimagic field*, and technically magical, which is the kind of magical rules interactions are concerned with.

The difference is explained in a Sage Advice Compendium entry:

> **Is the breath weapon of a dragon magical?** If you cast *antimagic field*, don armor of invulnerability, or use another feature of the game that protects against magical or nonmagical effects, you might ask yourself, “Will this protect me against a dragon’s breath?” The breath weapon of a typical dragon isn’t considered magical, so *antimagic
> field* won’t help you but armor of invulnerability will.
> You might be thinking, “Dragons seem pretty magical to me.” And yes, they are extraordinary! Their description
> even says they’re magical. But our game makes a distinction between two types of magic:
>
> - the background magic that is part of the D&D multiverse’s physics and the physiology of many D&D creatures
> - the concentrated magical energy that is contained in a magic item or channeled to create a spell or other focused magical effect
>   In D&D, the first type of magic is part of nature. It is no more dispellable than the wind. A monster like a dragon
>   exists because of that magic-enhanced nature.
>
> The second type of magic is what the rules are concerned about. When
> a rule refers to something being magical, it’s referring to that second type.
>
> Determining whether a game feature is
> magical is straightforward. Ask yourself these questions about the feature:
>
> - Is it a magic item?
> - Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell
>   that’s mentioned in its description?
> - Is it a spell attack?
> - Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?
> - Does its description say it’s magical?
>
> If your answer to any of those questions is yes, the feature is magical.

The description of the fairy does not even call the fairy magical, it merely says it is "imbued with" magic. The fairy is only "background" magical. Many other creatures are background magical in this way, like dragons, sorcerers ("*Magic is a part of every sorcerer, suffusing body, mind, and spirit*"*, p. 99 *PH*), or any other creature that is of a race with innate spellcasting. All of these are "background" magical. *Antimagic field* does nothing to harm them or wink them out.

(It will however stop them from using features that are magical under the criteria listed above).

Comment: I changed “degrees” of magical to “categories”, as it better fits what you’re describing.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't disagree with the overall answer, but "imbued with magic" vs "magical" is a thin branch to walk out on, especially give 5e's lack of overall precision about things like this.

Comment: @Novak No doubt. I find this entire distinction between ambient magic and full-on, mechanical magic questionable, but that's how it is. Imbued with, according to the dictionary is "filled with", so the thing filled is not magical itself. Its even worse for sorcerers in my mind, "*suffused* with magic in body, mind and spirit" sounds even worse a case than just imbued with it; but I guess the same logic applies: the sorcerer is not magical, they are just suffused with it.

Comment: I would really like an updated system that actually thinks through rules and carefully defines terms, and uses those definitions.  But you're right, it is what it is.

Comment: @Novak: It may be best to think of this as more of a balance rule than an in-universe rationale. It is in much the same category as *Fireball*'s exclusion of worn or carried items - it would make more logical sense for *Fireball* to affect every item in the sphere, but that would be overpowered for a third-level spell. If *Antimagic Field* could instantaneously kill large subsets of the Monster Manual, no save allowed, then it might seem reasonable (if a bit strong) for an eighth-level spell, but it would be impractical for the DM to use without messing up the campaign.

Answer (score 19):

### A Fairy can exist in an antimagic field just fine.

There are a few ways to get to this conclusion; chief among them are:

### Antimagic Field doesn't say so.

[Antimagic Field](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field)'s effects on creatures (and objects) is limited to:

> A creature or object summoned or created by magic temporarily winks out of existence in the sphere. Such a creature instantly reappears once the space the creature occupied is no longer within the sphere.

At worst, a fairy might be considered to be "created by magic" and, thus, would temporarily wink out of existence if they found themselves within an antimagic field; were this to happen, though, they'd be fine when the field either moved or dissipated. This GM finds this interpretation, at best, highly suspect, however: "infused with" and "created by" are very different things.

Note that some of the Fey Characteristics on that table could reasonably be suppressed by an antimagic field (eg., #4, "a glittering mist constantly surrounds you"). A canny player might recognize that their magical mist being suppressed means that something odd is afoot.

### The Fairy racal description doesn't say so.

The [Fairy's racial traits](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/814913-fairy) are meant to call out anything mechanical that the player of a Fairy needs to know. Antimagic Field is a well-known spell, and the fairy's connection to the Feywild's magic is explicitly mentioned in the race's description. Absent, however, is any mention that ill effects await a fairy who finds themselves in such a field.

Also, compare the [Animated Armor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16786-animated-armor)'s statblock, which explicitly calls out its Antimagic Susceptibility. Granted, it's a monster statblock rather than a PC race, but it's still evidence that the racial description would include something similar (thanks [@Kirt](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/23547/kirt) for the pointer).

### It's game-breakingly bad design.

I admit that I haven't read every single spell WotC's published in 5e, but I cannot think of a single spell that instantly kills a (playable) creature - even if it's limited to only certain types of (playable) creatures - 100% of the time, without anything that the player or party can do to prevent the death. There's no attack that needs to hit, no save to mitigate the effects, not even a clear and obvious visual effect to indicate "something weird is happening here". For that one spell to be an [Abjuration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#SchoolofAbjuration) spell - the school "that blocks, banishes, or protects" - to be the one that simply kills a creature in that manner beggars belief.

At the end of the day, D&D is a game. Having an effect in the game - in the base rules, not something that a GM's come up with - that simply erases one of the characters breaks the implicit social contract that underlies (or should) every D&D game in existence: "we're here to have fun".

Comment: You might further note that for _creatures_, if they have a reaction to being in an antimagic field, their stat block says so.  Animated Armor, for example, has: "**Antimagic Susceptibility**. The armor is incapacitated while in the area of an antimagic field. If targeted by dispel magic, the armor must succeed on a Constitution saving throw against the caster's spell save DC or fall unconscious for 1 minute."  If faeries had such a reaction, it would be described in the rules for playing them as a PC.

Comment: Great answer. Power Word Kill instantly snuffs out most creatures, unless they have more than 100 hits. At the levels you normally encounter opponents who have this some PCs may be above that threshold while at full health, but others may well not be — for example wizards average less than 100 hit on average up to level 20, unless they have Con bonuses.

Comment: I once built this whole wild strategy around being undead and taking advantage of the miswording of antimagic field that caused all undead rather than just summoned undead to wink out in antimagic fields, to protect me from being hit by my own city buster. Yeah; that wording was broken.

Comment: If the fairy was **"created by magic"** its description would say so. Man, I miss OG ecology entries.

Answer (score 3):

To add some perspective to other answers and comments: Fairies might have magic flowing through them, but they're still the product of 2 creatures reproducing. As far as I know the D&D lore, Fairies aren't summoned creatures, they're born into their world. They're not magical constructs, they just have innate magical abilities. Their wings aren't magical either, they can naturally support the weight of the fairy. The "imbued with magic" is just a flavor sentence about the creature, similar to how Mountain Dwarves mention they're "accustomed to difficult life in rugged terrain" without getting mechanical advantages in rugged terrain.